# reuse hooks from compass' config.rb

Tags: ruby, compass

I have multiple shops, each being a standalone project. What I need is a way to include common hooks from a library of hooks from a location shared across them (in the following code, only `on_stylesheet_saved`.

config.rb looks something like this:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public/css/live/"
sass_dir = "public/css/entrypoints"
images_dir = "public/library/images"
javascripts_dir = "public/library/javascript"
additional_import_paths = [ "public/library/css" ]

output_style = (environment == :production) ? :compressed : :expanded

relative_assets = false

if environment == :production
    on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
          #do stuff
    end
else
    load 'temp.rb'
end
```

the line `load 'temp.rb'` is executed, however the hook inside is not, when I change a scss file:

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
    puts "XXX #{filename}"
end
```

How to properly load this `temp.rb` hook without duplicating the code across all shops?

PS: the project is not in ruby, and I'm not a ruby programmer. The code base is of medium size, over 300k LOCs, so no big refactorings come into question. We are merely using compass as a tool.

Comment: What type of content is in `temp.rb`?

Comment: @Denis temp.rb contains ruby code, just like the snippet above, with the declaration of `on_stylesheet_saved` and a `puts "XXX #{filename}"`. Of course, it will do more, this is just a (reproducible) POC.

Comment: There might be some scope or context-related shenanigans going on. Is the output of `p self` identical in `config.rb` and `temp.rb`? If not, I'd suggest reading the file's contents as a string, and `eval`'ing or `instance_eval`'ing the ruby code to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: `p self` shows in config.rb `#<Compass::Configuration::FileData:0x00000000af6a68 @name="application/Myshop/configs/config.rb", @top_level=#<Compass::Configuration::FileData:0x00000000af6a68 ...>, @inherited_data=#<Compass::Configuration::Data:0x00000000af7378 @name="cli_defaults", @set_attributes={:environment=>true}, @top_level=#<Compass::Configuration::Data:0x00000000af7378 ...>, @environment=:development>, @set_attributes={}>` and in temp.rb it shows `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, there's a chance that the context is different in the two files.

Seeing how `p self` is, in config.rb:

```
#<Compass::Configuration::FileData:0x00000000af6a68 ...>
```

... vs `main` in `temp.rb`.

I'd advise one of two options:

1. Read the file as a string and `eval` it: `eval str`
2. Read the file as a string and `instance_eval` it: `instance_eval str, __FILE__, __LINE__`

The difference between the two isn't material in your particular case, since the context is that the object you're targeting already. Unless you're interested in having the precise file and line where a ruby error might be occurring.

For information though, `instance_eval`, `module_eval`, and `class_eval` offer a convenient way to change the context when needed:

```
class Foo; end
p self                           # main
Foo.new.instance_eval("p self")  # a Foo instance
Foo.new.module_eval("p self")    # undefined method
Foo.new.class_eval("p self")     # undefined method
Foo.instance_eval("p self")      # the Foo class
Foo.module_eval("p self")        # the Foo class
Foo.class_eval("p self")         # the Foo class
```

Answer (score 1):

To see the error, I had to use

```
require File.expand_path("temp", File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__)))
```

and to get it working I have used

```
eval(File.open(File.expand_path("temp.rb", File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__)))).read)
```

I hope this helps someone.

I don't like `eval` and I hope it's seen as bad in ruby as in the languages I program in, but it works and I have filed in a bug report at https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1898

Comment: `instance_eval` could have been an option too.

Comment: @Denis I would like to give you the bounty, otherwise it will go by default to the negative answer below. Please post an answer, what do you mean with `instance_eval` and why is it better? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean. You could try to flip the logic:

`if environment == :production
    on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
          #do stuff
    end
else
    load 'temp.rb'
end`

and write it like this:

`on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
   if environment == :production
       # do production stuff
   else
       load 'temp.rb'
   end
end`